# Establecer zona horaria en codeigniter 4 para cuba

Tags: php, codeigniter, php7, date, codeigniter-4

estoy usando la version 4.0.4 de Codeigniter, php 7 y necesito saber como cambiar la zona horaria, y en donde ubicar la configuracion, gracias y saludos.

Comment: Con el funcion `date_default_timezone_set`

Comment: @Excorpion, ¿en que parte de mi framework codeigniter puedo colocar date_default_timezone_set para usarlo en todo mi proyecto web?

Comment: Te lo dejo como respuesta

Comment: amigo excorpion, encontre en codeigniter 4.0.4 en app/Config/App.php esta variable public $appTimezone = 'America/Chicago' y la cambie por la que necesito America/Havana y listo, gracias

Comment: Perfecto ! eso saeteará el timezone para todas tus aplicaciones ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para establecer el default timezone por completo.
Puedes establecerlo en tu `php.ini`.
Para ello, dirígete a dicho archivo, y busca `date.timezone`
Quitale las marcas de comentario, editalo a tu preferencia y listo.

```
date.timezone = "America/Havana"
```

Recuerda siempre reiniciar apache en caso de cambios a la configuracion.
En caso de necesitar un timezone especifico, dirigete al siguiente [link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

Comment: Al parecer el timezone para Cuba es Havana, asi que lo dejo incluido.

Answer (score -1):

Tengo un helper con la siguiente función:

```
function ZonaHoraria(){
    return   date_default_timezone_set('America/Havana');
}
```

Y como en el  codeigniter 4 , se pede poner el helper en BaseController y todos los   controladores heredan de el, asunto resuelto.

Comment: Deberias dar una mejor explicacion.